# Python - Looking to remove remaining string using slice

Tags: python

Looking to remove the rest of a date input in the folllowing format: 2018-10-03 11:46:00. I want to remove the time portion. So far my code reads:

```
out1.due_date = out1.due_date[10:]
```

I am using a program called Data 360, and the out1 is what is used to process the records. However, I am a bit puzzled on how I could remove everything after the yyyy-mm-dd input.

Thanks!

Comment: 10: means from char 10 to the rest of the string. You want opposite :10 which means from beginning to char 10.

Answer (score 1):

Use split function to achieve this, the method splits a string into a list.You can specify the separator, default separator is a whitespace.
So out1.due_date.split() would return list ['2018-10-03','11:46:00']. Since interested in date , use zero as the index.

```
out1.due_date= out1.due_date.split()[0]
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Answer (score 0):

Using `fromisoformat` to parse the string to a datetime object and extracting date part out of it, by calling `date()` on it.

```
from datetime import date, datetime

print(datetime.fromisoformat(out1.due_date).date())
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.